# htaccess public some folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I use .HTACCESS file to serve up PHP pages from a `public` directory without showing `public` in the URL?

What I have in my .HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^bower_components($|/)
RewriteCond $1 !^node_modules($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

What I have on my file system for my project:

```
.htaccess
bower_components/
node_modules/
public/
    a/
        index.php
        some_other_page.php
    b/
    c/
src/ <------ should NOT be accessible to public
```

URLs

```
http://example.com/something/a/
http://example.com/something/a/index.php
http://example.com/something/a/some_other_page.php
http://example.com/something/b/
```

and so on.

The above .HTACCESS works fine for all cases except when there is no trailing slash.

This works: http://example.com/something/a/

This does not work: http://example.com/something/a

It redirects to http://example.com/something/public/a/ and gives a 404 Not Found error.

How do I make it work with and without a trailing slash??

Also tried values On and Off for the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive as suggested in a comment but results did not change.

This happens on both Apache 2.2.15 and Apache 2.4.18.

**UPDATE**

Logs for RewriteLogLevel 3 when accessing **without a trailing slash**:

```
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/project1/a -> a
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/project1/a -> a
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'a'
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] rewrite 'a' -> 'public/a'
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] add per-dir prefix: public/a -> /var/www/html/project1/public/a
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/project1/public/a -> /project1/public/a
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:12:54:38 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] internal redirect with /project1/public/a [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

And here are the logs **with the trailing slash**:

```
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/project1/a -> /var/www/html/project1/a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/project1/a/ -> a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/project1/a -> /var/www/html/project1/a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/project1/a/ -> a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'a/'
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] rewrite 'a/' -> 'public/a/'
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] add per-dir prefix: public/a/ -> /var/www/html/project1/public/a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/project1/public/a/ -> /project1/public/a/
192.168.33.1 - - [20/Apr/2017:13:02:45 --0400] [/sid#7f54b8915cf0][rid#7f54b8dc9748/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/project1/] internal redirect with /project1/public/a/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Comment: probably it is a [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) behavior.

Comment: @Deadooshka Both values `On` and `Off` for the `DirectorySlash` directive produce the same behavior here

Comment: `/something/a` rewrites to nonexistent file `/something/public/a` and goes to the next round where it may be affected with many Apache directives, such as DirectoryIndex, ErrorDocument, DirectorySlash etc. on any config level.

Comment: `[INTERNAL REDIRECT]` means new round of url processing. it's about the detailed Apache log with that redirect.